# Measuring distance from gridsquares to contours of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, bathymetry

I have a baselayer (.shp file), with bathymetric contours. I want to measure the distance from each grid square in a grid, to the nearest nominated depth (so was hoping to have a way to also nomate specifically to -120 m in the .shp file).

I generally have a basic understanding of the functions of QGIS, but have absolutely no idea where to start.

I'm using QGIS v3.2.1

I have tried the below answer from Kazuhito, but appear to be getting scores that are UTM figures. I've attached photos of where I am at now.

[image: How the map looks when coloured by "distance" scores.] i.e. not a true reflection of any distance to the 100 m contour.

[image: The script I used]

Comment: Thanks for the update, Joe. I am probably mistaken but the look of the picture shows the `100m` layer (contour line shape) is in edit mode. Does it mean you are  running the Field Calculator on this line attribute table? You need to do it on `Grid` layer attribute table.

Comment: No problems, thanks for responding so soon. No, I did that in a desperate troubleshooting attempt, I thought perhaps they both needed to be in edit mode for the calculation to work.

Answer (score 3):

With a simple test case:

[image]

An expression below calculated the shortest distance between each grid center to the contour at 3200m.

```
length(
 shortest_line(
    centroid($geometry), 
    closest_point(geometry(get_feature('Contours', 'ELEV', '3200')), $geometry)))
```

However, this example may be too simplistic. Please let me know if this expression works for your real case.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to output a sensible score the way it did for you. Please see edits for my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Different account because could never recover this one, but the way that worked for me in the end was getting Centroids from the grid (Vector->Geometry Tools->Centroids) and getting the vertices of the lines (Vector->Geometry Tools->Extract vertices). I then used the tool (from Processing Toolbox) Distance to Nearest Hub (Points). This measured the closest point from the contour layer to the centroid of the grid. Not perfect but it worked for what I needed.